# Underclocking RAM on an older motherboard

Tags: ramdisk

I have a Hp G32 laptop that only supports RAM up to 1333 MHz. I happen to have a 1600 MHz stick at 4gb and when I tried using it, it just crashed and bootlooped. Is there a way for me to use the RAM by underclocking it so that it doesn't crash? How stable would such a configuration be? I tried looking in the BIOS but it doesn't seem to have such a option.

Comment: Trying moving the 1600 to different slots.  Sometimes the 1st or last slot sets the rules, but I have no idea which is which for that laptop.

Comment: I read online that the motherboard seems to only support up to 1333

Comment: Your main problem is the BIOS is the only place you can force the memory speed.  1600Mhz RAM will run at 1333Mhz if the BIOS tells it to.